# How do I do a train and test split in a polars dataframe

Tags: python-polars

I am trying to find a simple way of randomly splitting a polars dataframe in train and test. This is how I am doing it right now

```
train, test = df
  .with_columns(pl.lit(np.random.rand(df0.height)>0.8).alias('split'))
  .partition_by('split')
```

however, this leaves an extra split column hanging in my dataframes that I need to drop after.

Comment: There is an open request for `.partition_by` to drop the columns: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/8808 - Could you shuffle the dataframe: `df.sample(fraction=1, shuffle=True)` and take `.head()` + `.tail()` or do you need random sized splits?

Comment: ah shuffle would work, thanks!

Comment: would you mind cleaning up and adding your comment as an answer so I can mark it

Comment: Yep sure thing, I wasn't sure if it answered the question properly or not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76546689/ may be a more suitable answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [open feature request](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/8808) for allowing `.partition_by` to drop keys.

As discussed in the comments, it is possible to shuffle a dataframe using [`.sample()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.sample.html#polars.DataFrame.sample)

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"val": range(100)})

df = df.sample(fraction=1, shuffle=True)
```

```
shape: (100, 1)
┌─────┐
│ val │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 64  │
│ 40  │
│ 39  │
│ 98  │
│ …   │
│ 21  │
│ 29  │
│ 87  │
│ 99  │
└─────┘
```

Which could then be split into parts e.g. using [`.head`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.head.html#polars.DataFrame.head) and [`.tail`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.tail.html#polars.DataFrame.tail)

```
test_size = 20
test, train = df.head(test_size), df.tail(-test_size)
```

```
>>> test
shape: (20, 1)
┌─────┐
│ val │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 60  │
│ 24  │
│ 96  │
│ 94  │
│ …   │
│ 50  │
│ 54  │
│ 56  │
│ 33  │
└─────┘
```

```
>>> train
shape: (80, 1)
┌─────┐
│ val │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 87  │
│ 38  │
│ 6   │
│ 37  │
│ …   │
│ 93  │
│ 77  │
│ 8   │
│ 23  │
└─────┘
```

Comment: on this line: `test, train = df.head(test_size), df.tail(-test_size)` aren't you supposed to use: `test, train = sample.head(test_size), sample.tail(-test_size)`? Your answer will just pull the first `test_size` rows for the test sample which is usually not what you want.